# yet another language!

Tags: 2013

I took a sabatical from programming for about eight years and now that I am back and developing a Sharepoint Intranet, I am so utterly lost.

I know HTML and have basic VBA programming experience but in my previous years, of course there was always a good design view of webpages / applications so you could actually SEE the parts you were building. Not so in SP2013....It is straight up code and that's fine but...

where do I start language wise? I thought Visual Studio would be good for me since I dabbled in VB Script & VBA but honestly, I am so overwhelmed with the mentions of css and aspx that I am unsure where my focus should be.

It almost looks like CSS has taken over web apps....should I start with, brush up on that to make this experience easier? I have had no issues creating a site and putting in simple add ins, columns, calendars, etc....

But what I really want to do is get my hands dirty and change it up. I hate the basic layout, I want to add better tabs in the header, change the default column sizes, etc....but silly me, I figured with my background I could look at & copy/paste a little code and be fine....what a slap back into reality, lol

SUGGESTIONS? (besides a Miller Lite and some Excedrin)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Focus on Client Side coding, like JavaScript. As Microsoft's focus is shifting more and more towards cloud, it will be the prevalent technology used to talk to your (SharePoint) sites.

[Microsoft Virtual Academy](https://mva.microsoft.com/) is a great place to start. 
Also, MS is offering 6 months worth of free Pluralsight training with [VS Dev Essentials](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/visual-studio-dev-essentials-vs.aspx) (sign up, on dashboard you see after sigining in click "get code" and then activate in the Pluralsight block).

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend client side code to begin with (JavaScript). It really depends what you want to build, but you can accomplish a lot without heavy coding. Also download SharePoint Designer. You might be getting a little ahead of yourself by going straight into Visual Studio and developing custom solutions.